# Error al crear la clase model

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-models

Estoy hace muchos días con este error y no se que es. alguien me puede ayudar ?saludos. ya probe varias cosas y hacer la migración de nuevo pero no me deja[image: Codigo de la clase Model y el Error]

Comment: por favor no coloques imagenes de codigo, colocalo como texto, igualmente el mensaje de error

Comment: Pon el codigo, es mas facil identificarlo que en imagenes

Answer (score 0):

debes añadir esto al atributo del modelo, `on_delete=models.CASCADE`, te debe de quedar asi:`first_player = models.ForeingKey(User, related_name="games_first_player", on_delete=models.CASCADE)` y con el segundo jugador tambien, a todos los campos que son llaves foraneas debes ponerselo, `second_player = models.ForeingKey(User, related_name="games_second_player", on_delete=models.CASCADE)`